# Integrating PayU money to Ionic + Cordova Hybrid App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, payu, payumoney

please  help me how to set or render success url to my ionic app.
when i integrating PayU money to Ionic app it requires Success Url and Failure Url after completion of payment it render into success url but it's not back to Ionic App.

```
<form name="sendParam" method="post"    action="https://test.payu.in/_payment.php">
    <input type="text" name="key" value="P3kHif" />
    <input type="text" name="txnid" value="mdd0123" />
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="100" />
    <input type="text" name="productinfo" value="oxygenconcentrator" />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="test@gmail.com" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="9999999999" />
    <input type="text" name="surl" value="http://example.com" />
    <input type="text" name="Furl" value="http://example.com/about-us/" />
    <input type="text" name="Hash" value="9a4c95b065ae294414e6a5b0b6e8e5d1a2ebf26074228eac6ff7c7d739c9cd4d021a9f70af8860ac369b1ccecfdaa60ba5839ee9dc1fd41e2848a3813677d520"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
 </form >
```

and response comes from PayUmoney is only in HTML format it doesn't have any JSON Object format. Just i followed the following Link [PayU Money Rest API](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html)

Comment: Hey, I am in a similar situation, did you figure out a solution to this ? I am using Meteor with Cordova ..

Comment: @Aman Did you find the correct URL to return to your app?

Comment: hai, sai. Did you find the solution? are u using in app browser for loading payu money?

Comment: Hi @SrinivasAppQube   sorry for delay..!!! finally I come up with using inappbrowser [LINK](https://github.com/IonicU/payuhybridappintegration)

Comment: how to pass the params dynamically to payubuzz.html. in  in app browser angular $scope is not working..

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube write business logic like attach controller to that view and pass the values

Comment: hello guys please help me I am also facing same problem. please post some flow and code here so that I can get idea as well to make payment from ionic.

Comment: @SunilRawat You can go through this link may it will helps you  https://github.com/IonicU/payuhybridappintegration

Comment: Yes, checked it but it did not tell us how to pass success and fail url to get response back on app after payment, and it does not tell how to genarate has key in app.js. If you have done it please share some details.

Comment: Please help I am in big trouble by choosing payumoney.

Comment: @SunilRawat you can see **iabLoadStop** method. which is used for when inappbrowser meets successurl it will close and send back response

Comment: @SunilRawat you can find the links to generate HashKey (https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Hash-generation/26) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602670/payumoney-integration-how-to-calculate-hash-for-comparing-with-response)   online ket generator :-  [http://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/]

Comment: it redirect to https://payu.herokuapp.com/success url on success / fail. I am not able to get any response back in this method:
function iabLoadStop(event) {
    
    if (event.url.match("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success")) {
        console.log(iabRef);
       });
I need to handle success and failure at my end to store response in db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139740/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-sai).

Comment: can we integrate with "bolt.launch" in ionic app?

Answer (score 3):

Payumoney does't have sdk for Hybrid applications. We need to use Cordova inapp browser to achieve this.

Step 1 : Create Payumoney Account and get sandbox details.

Step 2: Install Cordova inapp browser

Step 3: Create your payment url

Step 4 : Create success and failure url in server and add these urls in your payment page

Step 5: Run your payment url in your inapp browser.

Thats it. It will do a payment process and send a status to given success and failure url.

[Here](http://www.17educations.com/angularjs/payumoney-payment-gateway-ionic/) you can find a code for payment gateway integration in ionic.

Comment: can we integrate with "bolt.launch" in ionic app?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContextOver) throws JSONException {

    Intent intentScan = new Intent(this.cordova.getActivity().getBaseContext(), com.timepay.payu.activity.MainActivity.class);

    intentScan.putExtra("amount", "1000");

    intentScan.setPackage(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    callbackContext = callbackContextOver;

    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intentScan, 11);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: By default return type of this method is false, we need to set it to true that's work for me.

Comment: @AnkushModi, after change the return type to "true" i am getting the result as per expectation. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

I have being searching for the same but no luck. So end up doing lot of workaround to get it working with my IONIC 1 App.

My approach might not be perfect but I am able to get working payment for my ionic app.

First I thought of sharing my app with you guyz but there are few credentials I am packing with it so is not safe to share it here.
yes my app is live in playstore and have more than 100 active users (last time i checked)

Any ways let me show you how I did it in my app. 
Below is my code. Please see if anyone has a better approach please share.. 
    ` $scope.pay = function (address) {

```
        sharedUtils.showLoading("Processing Payment...");
        // sending data from app to server for preprocessing 
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://xyx.com/payment/getmobilepaymentdata',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            // below data contains all info collected form device page transitions like user address , order details etc. 
            data: data
        }
        var serverRes = {};
        if (datatobeshared !== undefined)
        //Note: response data will have all the required info we need to send it to payumoney
            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                serverRes = response.data;
                var data = 'key=' + serverRes.key
                    + '&txnid=' + serverRes.txnid
                    + '&amount=' + serverRes.amount
                    + '&productinfo=' + serverRes.productinfo
                    + '&firstname=' + serverRes.firstname
                    + '&email=' + serverRes.email
                    + '&phone=' + serverRes.phone
                    + '&surl=' + serverRes.surl
                    + '&furl=' + serverRes.furl
                    + '&hash=' + serverRes.hash
                    + '&service_provider='+serverRes.service_provider
                    + '&udf3=' + serverRes.udf3
                    + '&udf1=' + serverRes.udf1;

               // Note: check below option.This will be set in browser
                var options = {
                    "location": "no",
                    "toolbar": "no",
                    "hardwareback": "no",
                    "clearcache": "no"
                };
                $rootScope.paymentwindow = window.open('templates/payuBiz.html?' + data, '_blank', 'location=no');
                sharedUtils.hideLoading();



// here I am updating a status flag i.e -1 on server side which my server will update to 0(on failure) or 1(on Success)                   fireBaseData.refOrderStatus().child(serverRes.txnid).update({
                    status: -1,
                });
         // once window with payumoney will open in our app we will keep checking status flag that we have set above and put a timeout for session incase user let device and didn't perform any action on payment page
                $rootScope.timesRun = 0;
                $rootScope.interval = setInterval(function () {
                    console.log($rootScope.timesRun);
                    $rootScope.timesRun += 1;

                    if ($rootScope.timesRun >= 50) {
                        clearInterval($rootScope.interval);
                        clearInterval($rootScope.interval);
                        $rootScope.paymentwindow.close();
                        sharedUtils.showAlert('Payment Session Time out', 'Payment gateway session got time out.');

                        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                            historyRoot: true
                        });
                        $state.go('lastOrders', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});
                        return;
                    }

                    if ($rootScope.paymentwindow.closed) {
                        clearInterval($rootScope.interval);
                        sharedUtils.showAlert('Payment error', 'Payment got interrupted unexpectedly. Please try again.');
                        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                            historyRoot: true
                        });
                        $state.go('lastOrders', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});
                        return;
                    }


                    fireBaseData.refOrderStatus().child($rootScope.txnid).child('status').once("value", function (snapshot) {


                        if (snapshot.val() != -1) {
                            $rootScope.paymentwindow.close();

                            if (snapshot.val() == 1) {
                                clearInterval($rootScope.interval);

                                $scope.orderSuccess(address, $rootScope.txnid);

                                return;
                            } else {
                                clearInterval($rootScope.interval);
                                $scope.orderFailure(address);
                                return;

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, 5000);


            }, function (error) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    template: 'This is some error in processing your order Please retry ' + JSON.stringify(error.data)
                });
                return;

            });
        sharedUtils.hideLoading();

    }`
```

rest of the code is self explanatory.

Hope this will help.

here is my payumoney templet`

```
<h2 style="text-align: center">Your will be taken to paytment gateway </br> Please dont use back button or move app in background</h2>
<div align="center">
<div class="loader" ></div></div>

<form id = "payuForm" name="payuForm" method="post" action="https://secure.payu.in/_payment">
  <!--<form id = "payuForm" name="payuForm" method="post" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">-->

  <input type="hidden" name="key" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="phone" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="surl" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="furl" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="udf3" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="udf1" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="enter" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>

<script>

  function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
      tmp = [];
    location.search
      .substr(1)
      .split("&")
      .forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
      });
    return result;
  }

  try {
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="firstname"]').val(findGetParameter('firstname'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="email"]').val(findGetParameter('email'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="hash"]').val(findGetParameter('hash'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="phone"]').val(findGetParameter('phone'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="productinfo"]').val(findGetParameter('productinfo'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="amount"]').val(findGetParameter('amount'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="key"]').val(findGetParameter('key'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="txnid"]').val(findGetParameter('txnid'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="surl"]').val(findGetParameter('surl'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="furl"]').val(findGetParameter('furl'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="udf3"]').val(findGetParameter('udf3'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="udf1"]').val(findGetParameter('udf1'));
    $('form[name="payuForm"] input[name="service_provider"]').val(findGetParameter('service_provider'));

    setTimeout(function () {
      document.payuForm.submit();
    }, 1000);
  }catch (e)
  {
    alert(e);
  }
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Update : 2020
Payu released Cordova Plugin For integrating in Hybrid Apps
https://developer.payumoney.com/payumoney-cordova-plugin/

They have also Provided Wrapper JS files to call Native SDK Plugin