# PayuMoney with Ionic 2 Android Application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, payment-gateway, payumoney

Can someone tell me how to integrate PayUMoney with Ionic 2 Android Application?

Comment: I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355720/integrating-payu-money-to-ionic-cordova-hybrid-app

Comment: @ifti, Your answer is for ionic 1, Is there anything for ionic 2/3?

Comment: @KarthikRP not but same thing should work once you migrate it to TS.  Other thing is i have stopped using Payumoney as they are lot of problem to get money back from them, still have Rs 10000 with them CC mail chain is going on.  Please check razor https://razorpay.com/ once.. They have plugin for cordova and hybrid app.. and you can embed their payment page inside your custom components as well.. hope this help

Comment: Its not my decision to go with payU, the order comes from higher lords. Well, will try it out with ionic 2.